# What does it mean when someone says "noted" to you?

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english, social-interaction

I was talking to my friend about something I find disgusting and she replied, "Noted."

I replied, "Noted what?" and she said, "All that."

I am a little confused about what she was trying to say? Is there more here than meets the eye? Does "noted" as a response convey a meaning beyond the simple word itself?

Comment: It's a slang for "Got it" or "I understood"...

Comment: "Noted" in conversation usually means something like: "I've made a mental note about your feelings on the subject."

Comment: At one of the magazines where I worked long ago, we occasionally received off-the-wall rants submitted as letters to the editor. Rather than responding point-by-point to an argument that (often) made little sense and entailed huge leaps in logic or assumption, or pretending that we agreed entirely with the letter writer, we often replied with the single word "Noted," signifying merely "We have received your communiqué." Not that the poster's friend in this case is pursuing a similar strategy...

Comment: What did you find disgusting?

Comment: This is really not a bad question. Please do not vote to close.

Comment: Voting to reopen.

Comment: Okay so help me out of here. Regardless of whether this question is too basic for this site: why didn't you just ask your friend? They produced the word, they knew exactly what they meant, they were available for comment, and you were already talking to them. But rather than just asking them, you ask a bunch of random strangers off the Internet. Why?

Comment: Probably the OP was perceptive enough to see that the friend was being dismissive.  So the OP found a site where the meaning and nuances of a word would be discussed.  In my experience "Noted" has always been dismissive.

Answer (score 11):

Actually this is not a bad question.

When you make a statement and the reply comes back "Noted," you can assume that you have been over-sharing, discussing topics the other person finds objectionable or uncomfortable, or violating some other social taboo.

It is a one-word way of saying, "I don't wish to discuss this and I wish you would stop talking about it."

Additional tidbit: *The New Yorker* magazine uses this in their end-of-article squibs in precisely this manner. They find some odd or borderline-offensive bit of published text and put after it the one-word comment: "Noted."

Answer (score 7):

Noted is slang for, "I have taken note." Its meaning in context would depend on the speaker's tone of voice.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, when people have said, "Noted," or, more often, "So noted," it means that they have heard me, or pretended to have heard me, and that they have no intention of acting on my issue. It's  an approach some people use to foreclose further discussion. It's dismissive. It means you're not going to get anywhere.