# How does one say to someone that he paid attention to something they said?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I used to think that "noted" meant just that. But from [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239350/what-does-it-mean-when-someone-says-noted-to-you) question's replies, it seems that that is (mainly) used with a negative connotation. So how would I point out to someone that I took what they said seriously (preferably with a connotation of gratefulness for the information)?

Also, in cases where it is spoken, the tone of my voice might help clarify my meaning, but when it's written it's even more complicated.

Comment: if you were paying attention to someone/something, you were being 'Attentive'. Is what you want to convey?

Comment: @BhoomikaArora I want more than that. One can be attentive and still ignore/disagree.

Comment: Noted can be as neutral as a judge stating that a certain point is "granted."

Comment: Unfortunately, because so many people are insincere, you might have to just come out and explain that you really are grateful for the counsel.

Answer (score 1):

You could say ***duly noted*** instead of just *noted*.  I think that gives it the feeling of both seriousness and gratitude you are looking for.

e.g.

Friend:  "You know, John, you really should think of complimenting your wife every now and then."
John:  "Yes.  Duly noted."

Comment: I actually find the fuller 'duly noted' only adds to the sarcasm when it is meant as a slur.  So you have to have the context or the tone of voice. Similarly, I hear "Good to know" and "Now I'm up to speed" to mean either what they say, or to mean "Oh, Lord, save me. TMI (too much information)"  Say I tell you my results of drinking prune juice last night.  If you say "Duly noted" I should understand that you got my meaning, preferred fewer details, and are more than ready now to drop the subject.  After all, you already noted what I said with all the weight it was *due*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin -- Good point about motive and tone of voice.  So often the usage of words comes down to the heart of the individual using those words.  So, should we start using emojis more frequently?

Comment: @thomj1332 Do they have an emoji for "what I said is what I meant"? :)

Answer (score -1):

What about, "Understood"?

Granted, I say "noted" all the time. "Understood" is a second favorite.